# Why does IO Dispatchers create more than 64 thread in Kotlin corotines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

As I understood, Maximum number of threads that can be created by Dispatchers.IO is 64, but my result is a little bit tricky.

this is my code.

```
repeat(500) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
}
```

and this is the result.

```
...

DefaultDispatcher-worker-18
DefaultDispatcher-worker-46
DefaultDispatcher-worker-17
DefaultDispatcher-worker-47
DefaultDispatcher-worker-69
DefaultDispatcher-worker-64
DefaultDispatcher-worker-66
DefaultDispatcher-worker-67
DefaultDispatcher-worker-68
DefaultDispatcher-worker-41

...
```

Why is my threadpool count bigger than 64?
Does that mean my actual threads was created more than 64?

thank you for reading!
please help me

Comment: Max thread rented from `CommonPool` by `Dispatchers.IO` is 64. `Dispatchers.Default` can still create more threads, if all 64 is busy by coroutines in `Dispatchers.IO` upto your core count. [In playground](https://pl.kotl.in/bpOWDBZiO), it doesn't seem to have more threads than 64. Are you launching in other dispatchers as well?

Comment: No, that's all in the code. And afik, Default Dispatchers can create threads up to number of CPU core. If this right, I think the maximum number of threads Default Dispatchers would create is only 12...wouldn't it? why my coroutine works like that?

Comment: And also in my case, I use IO Dispatchers is that code. So even If you're right, my code is still a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Dispachers.IO names it's threads, but I only get 64 coroutines running at a time.

If you want to limit it to the number of CPUs you have you need to set this system property : `kotlinx.coroutines.io.parallelism`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {


    class Counter {
        private var current=0
        private var max=0
        fun addOne() {
            synchronized(this) {
                current++
                max = Math.max(max,current)

            }
        }
        fun subOne() {
            synchronized(this) {
                current--
            }
        }
        fun getMax() = max
    }

    val counter=Counter()

    val jobs = (0..500).map {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            counter.addOne()
            Thread.sleep(100)
            counter.subOne()
        }
    }
    var done = false
    while(!done) {
        val j = jobs.find{it.isActive}
        if( j == null) {
            done = true
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(100)
        }
    }

    println("max = ${counter.getMax()}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question. Your code works properly even in my pc condition. I think the problem is my code, can you tell me what's the problem with my code above?

Comment: I didn't see any problem w/ you code. If you print out the thread names in my code you get numbers above 64 as well. I just think that Dispatchers.IO's naming of the thread has nothing to do w/ it's internal thread count.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much! I spent a lot of time to handle this problem... now solved it!

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of official kotlin manual, more than 64 (default parallelism) threads can be created (but not used) during operations over IO dispatcher because of thread-sharing feature of coroutine.

Please refer to
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html.

Comment: The documentation was edited since I raised an issue on the official github. This thread  is as of before I raised that issue. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting my own article :

> Dispatcher.Default has limited to the number of CPU cores while
> **Dispatcher.IO has an elastic thread pool with a configurable max size**, who are expected to spend most of their time in a non-runnable
> state, awaiting the completion of an IO operation.

more can be found here: [Kotlin Coroutines for Android - The ABC’s](https://medium.com/@sarahmaher_16059/kotlin-coroutines-for-android-the-abcs-e80204a6101a)